# How to add environment variables for a website deployed on vercel

Tags: nuxt.js, vercel

How can i add `enivronment variables` for a website deployed on `vercel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use some obscure website called google.com to find a link to [this page](https://vercel.com/blog/environment-variables-ui).